# Handling received ACK frame in ath9k_htc module

Tags: linux, wifi

I want to measure a time when an ack frame is received.

I am using *TL-WN722N* **USB-type** WLAN card from *TP-LINK*. `ath9k_htc` kernel module is for the WLAN card.

I've inserted the following code in a highlighted line of [`ath9k_htc_rx_tasklet()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/htc_drv_txrx.c#L1083) in `htc_drv_txrx.c`:

```
if (ieee80211_is_ack(hdr->frame_control)) {
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "ath9k: received ack\n");
}
```

so that finally, the function is like [this](https://gist.github.com/gsongsong/991705f9c38ce6a9cda7#file-gistfile1-txt-L37)

After building and replacing kernel, I've checked with `dmesg`. But, nothing appears in the log.

After some googling, some says it is not `ath9k_htc_rx_tasklet()` but [`ath_rx_tasklet()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/recv.c#L992) in `recv.c`. Thus, I've inserted the same code into `ath_rx_tasklet()`, but the result is same, nothing appears in the log.

Is it impossible to check whether the *TL-WN722N* WLAN card received an ack frame in `ath9k*` modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't answer your specific question, but generally you will never see acks unless the driver is in monitor mode and you are actually sniffing the air.

Comment: This is true when you're trying to access a monitor-mode WLAN device from a userspace program. However, the driver in the kernel must properly receive ACKs even in managed mode. So I would guess that the code is simply inserted in the wrong place.